# PROBLEMA INTELLIJ + JAVA

Tags: java, classes, intellij-idea

Boa noite antes de tudo queRO dizer que sou totalmente iniciante e estou fazendo um curso de java na Udemy e quando estou criando uma class o nome da class fica em destaque vermelho e não consegue "interagir" com atributo/metodos.

e outra coisa o intellij esta criando este arquivo iml, é normal ?? pois em outros que criei nao aparecia este arquivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -3):

Olá, provavelmente ela está em vermelho pelo motivo de você ter versionado no Git.
Provavelmente não tem relação com os métodos e atributos.
para confirmar abaixo no canto esquerdo tem a campo Git, clica la é veja se esta versionado o projeto.